# Not able to retreive images data from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am working on an application like Olx where any user can list their items. So for that, I have a fragment to upload the photos of the item user wants to list on the application.
Now the problem is that when the user uploaded the photos to the firebase now I am confused how can I retrieve the same photos to the same user to show on the recycler view on the home screen??? please guide me on how can i achieve that.

Comment: Need more info/code sample to properly answer. Are you talking about re downloading a picture from firebase? just taking the image object and displaying it in another screen after uploading? Needs context and code

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, here is a [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) that might help, as it explains how to upload and how to display the uploaded image.

Comment: @AlexMamo sir can i use this resource to multiple store multiple image's url and then retrieve them???

Comment: Yes, as long as you provide different names for each image.

Comment: @AlexMamo sir i tried this documentation as this is in kotlin but did not get much, Can you provide any documents or any help in java if possible sir. thank you